# How to define an end point for VtPluse in ADS

Tags: voltage, ads

Generate voltage pulses using VtPulse in ADS.

It creates a stream of pulses defined.

Now I am thinking how to end it? for example if I want to stop this pulses at 1u sec.

How should I do it?

[image]